# create contact form with google maps of my location using html

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I'm a beginner in `html` and `css` and I want to make a `contact us form` where I want to add a small image of google maps with a specific address I want . I have no problem making the contact form but since I am a beginner I do not know  how to insert google maps with my location . An idea I had was to take a screenshot from google maps and add it but I would like the map to be interactive .
I would appreciate your help with this . Thank you in advance .

Comment: Depending upon the amount of traffic your site will receive should help determine if that is the best approach. If the traffic volume is lower than Google's "FREE" maps quota then probably OK. Otherwise I'd suggest a static map that when clicked will load the dynamic map with all the functionality you need. Doing this means your quota is not affect by simple passing traffic - only by those that wish to interact

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius It is a front end project for university . Should there be a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use iframe with your location, like

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY
    &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

It's very easy, just copy paste your location URL from google maps to src of the iframe.

You can read more here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-started